# Error in product attribute creation

Tags: magento2, product-attribute

While Creating New Product Attribute , 
the error:

> Class Magento\SalesRule\Model\ResourceModel\Rule\CollectionFactory does not exist

Comment: You can post your code lines?

Answer (score 1):

This might be a file permission issue. I was faced the same error and now got resolved after few debugging.

```
Set the file permission for below path.

sudo chmod -R 777 var/
sudo chmod -R 777 pub/
```